# C# running same copies of the program for MPI

Tags: c#, mpi

Can I compile same copies with visual studio 2013 ultimate?

For example; there is a ring.exe and the cmd command will be "mpiexec -np 4 ring.exe" to run it 4 times to get different rank numbers.

Can I do it in visual studio without geting in to cmd?

says this:

if (comm.Size < 2)

```
            // Our ring needs at least two processes
            System.Console.WriteLine("The Ring example must be run with at least two processes.
            System.Console.WriteLine("Try: mpiexec -np 4 ring.exe"
```

How to add comman line arguments this -> mpiexec -np 4 currentproject.exe

SOLVED: in debug: start external program: Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 SDK\Bin\mpiexec.exe

comman line arguments -np 4 ConsoleApplication2.exe

working dir: \Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\

Comment: no such thing I guess.. :)

Comment: maybe in command line arguments of visual studio but..

Answer (score 0):

Your question actually makes no sense, but I think I know what you want to say.

First of all clarification:

1. you build 1 binary (exe) using Visual Studio. Visual Studio's compiler job is done.
2. Then you run external program that runs this exe four times, making "4 copies" as 4 processes, not making actual copies of exe.

If you want to run external program when you press "F5" or whatever you have as "Debug" button, you need to go to `project settings -> Debug -> Start action -> Start external program`

Comment: No.. I just want to do the same thing as I am doing in cmd.. I want visual studio starts program with these arguments mpiexec -np 4 ring.exe  where ring.exe will be the current projects exe.

Comment: when you type `mpiexec -np 4 ring.exe` it actually starts `mpiexec`, not your executable. `mpiexec` then starts your executable 4 times, passing MPI-specific parameters